# Need to update id column using row_number()

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with `user_id` and `user_name` columns. I have to another column as `ID`. I want to populate the ID as below.

| User_id | User_name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 1 |
| 456 | BCD | 1 |
| 123 | ABC | 2 |
| 123 | ABC | 3 |
| 234 | XYZ | 1 |

First it needs to find the unique `user_id` and its number of occurrences and then assign 1 to n number based on the occurrences.

I am able to get the output by using row_number()

```sql
select row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as seq ,user_id,user_name from test_csv
```

How can I update ID with `seq` coming out of above query.

Comment: please provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `MERGE` statement and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
MERGE INTO test_csv dst
USING (
  SELECT row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as seq 
  FROM   test_csv
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET id = seq;
```

or a correlated `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE test_csv dst
SET id = (
           SELECT seq
           FROM   (
             SELECT row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as seq 
             FROM   test_csv
           ) src
           WHERE src.ROWID = dst.ROWID  
         );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_csv (User_id, User_name, ID) AS
SELECT 123, 'ABC', CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 'BCD', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'ABC', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'ABC', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 234, 'XYZ', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE` or `UPDATE`, the table contains:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 1 |
| 456 | BCD | 1 |
| 123 | ABC | 2 |
| 123 | ABC | 3 |
| 234 | XYZ | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FepNIcWI)

Comment: Thanks @MT0. This is working fine.  I have a process where i need to provide the mappings to application to load this data.      
Application runs the command as update test_csv set seq= and takes the query that i provide.  If i just provide the below query in the condition.
SELECT seq
           FROM   (
             SELECT row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id) as seq 
             FROM   test_csv
           ) src
           WHERE src.ROWID = ROWID  )
This will not work as single row returns multiple rows in sub query.. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @nav You will never get two rows with the same `ROWID` as it is a pseudo-column that is effectively a pointer directly to the row. The query in the answer has multiple rows within the same partition and it demonstrates that it works without errors.